# Issue calling Python script from Matlab process in cron

Tags: python, linux, matlab, python-2.7, cron

I have automatized a script to upload a file to a webpage. The script that generates the file is written in Matlab (2013a), and the file is uploaded to the webpage by means of a python function that is called from the Matlab script using the `system` command. The python script uses selenium.

The Matlab script runs perfectly when I launch it from the Linux command line, but when I put this script in a cron file it fails due to a problem with python. I get an error message when importing webdriver, this is the message (as part of the output of the python function):

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

> from selenium import webdriver ImportError: No module named selenium

I added the following line to the script just to know where the selenium package is located:

```
print webdriver.__file__
```

and I get this when calling the Matlab script from the shell:

> /home/myself/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/**init**.pyc

So, whats the difference between calling a script from the command line and call this function from a cron file?

From command line:

```
myself@server:~$ matlab2013b -nodesktop -nosplash -r OP_SCRIPT('A','B','C')
```

From cron file:

```
00 16 * * * myself matlab2013b -nodesktop -nosplash -r OP_SCRIPT('A','B','C')"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably you should set the Python path in cron first.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem adding the complete path of the python interpeter to python function when calling it from matlab:

```
[status, cmd_out] = system(['/home/myself/anaconda2/bin/python ',path_py,'sendFile.py "' filename '" "' path_py '"']);
```

instead of what I was doing previously:

```
[status, cmd_out] = system(['python ',path_py,'sendFile.py "' filename '" "' path_py '"']);
```